# Timezone offset issue

Tags: php

Working on a mod where a user inputs a datetime in this format "11/28/2012 11:34 am".

I am then using strtotime to convert it to a timestamp and saving it to my database.

I am then displaying it to the user in my template using the following date(DateTime, 'D M jS g:i A').

The problem is users who are not in the same timezone as the user who created the event do not get the correct time updated to reflect their timezone.

I have access to both timezone offset's of the user posting and the user viewing.

MY question is how should I compensate for timezone differences?

Comment: use GMT offset before converting. E.g. "11/28/2012 11:34 am +2 GMT"

Comment: EL, when I save it to the DB or when I display it to the user  and where are you getting +2 GMT ?

Comment: @Residual Envy: both. 1st - you change usertyped date to "Greenwich Mean Time" (GMT0) and 2nd - while displaying to user with known time offset (GMT+[u_said_u_know_it]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting the string to the real timezone use this to override server time zone with time zone of the user submitting the value: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

When retrieving it later, use the same function to override server time zone to current user's one (the one that is appropriate for the user displaying datetime at the moment).

Also make sure you store it properly in the database: preferably using Unix timestamps within PHP, TIMESTAMP columns within database, FROM_UNIXTIME() database function when saving to the database and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() when retrieving from database (all are valid for MySql RDBMS, check your own DBMS if it is different).

Comment: That might work except I only have access to the offset not the named timezone.

Comment: @ResidualEnvy: That _will_ work if done correctly. Check time zones with names starting with "Etc/" on the list of available time zone identifiers in the "Others" section: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php